# Save as vector from For Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have a very simple question here. I have been trying to save my results from the loop as a vector. Below is my reproducible code:-

```
a = matrix( c(0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
b = matrix( c(0.02, 0.45, 0.15, 0.30),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)

d = 0
myvector <- c()

for (i in 1:2) {
    d = d + (a[, i] * b[, i]) 
    myvector[i] <- d
}

myvector
[1] 0.014 0.149
```

Why it did not give me the whole vector? It only give me the answer for the first row. How do we store the result from the loop as vector?

Comment: You should try to vectorize your code instead of using for loops. For example, look at the results of `a*b` and `rowSums(a*b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a  = matrix( c(0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
b   = matrix( c(0.02, 0.45, 0.15, 0.30),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
d = 0
myvector <- vector()
for (i in 1:2){
 d = d + (a[,i] * b[,i]) 
myvector <- c(myvector, d)
}
```